# win32:libs undefined reference

Tags: qt, dll, libs

I want to link a .lib in my Qt project and I get an error about an undefined reference to `vhtIOConn::getDefault(vhtIOConn::DeviceType)`.

I have already added the following specifications to the .pro file:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) vie 28. ago 12:48:10 2009
######################################################################

TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

LIBS += "C:\agregar\VirtualHandCore.lib"
LIBS += "C:\agregar\VirtualHandDevice.lib"
LIBS += "C:\agregar\VirtualHandRegistry.lib"

# Input
HEADERS += "C:/Documents and Settings/halvarado/Mis documentos/respaldos de Qt/Development/include/vhandtk/vhtBase.h"
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are the libs built using the same compiler (msvc vs. mingw)? Do the VirtualHand* libs export the symbols needed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to a pc now, but try removing the quotes and using slash instead of backslash as separator for the lib paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
win32 : LIBS += $$quote(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\glew32s.lib)
win32 : LIBS += $$quote(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\gltools.lib)
```

this is how

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, I'm currently working with Qt 5 in linux.

what I did was to add in the name_of_your_project.pro this line

```
LIBS += -luiohook
```

you could try it, just change uiohook for the name of the lib you want to link. I hope this helps.